# Completly remove margin with tcpdf when printing the document

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm using tcpdf to create a report. I have an image in the header and in the footer. When I generate the pdf (view on the screen), I successfully removed the margins. But, when I print it, is there a way to remove the margin set for the printing?

My customer would like to have a document like if they print on a paper that already have the header/footer.

Is this possible? (first picture is what I see on the screen after generate the pdf, second picture is what I get when I want to print it)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done via PHP nor TCPDF. You either have to change the printing configurations of the program used to print or the ones of the printer. And the printer has to support printing without margins.

Comment: ok thanks. This is what I thought but I wanted to be sure before answering to my customer...

Comment: Yeah, most digital printers can't/won't print to the edge. I know inkjet printers will often provide a function for printing borderless photos, but I have never seen this for document printing. Laser printers usually won't print to the edge either. What graphic designers usually do to "bleed ink to the edge" is design the artwork to be printed on oversized paper and then the output is guillotined to the regular paper size, creating the illusion that the printer actually printed to the edge of the paper.